# Can Scss mixins be responsive

Tags: css, responsive-design, sass

In my css I have different font styles* for different devices:

e.g.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 599px) {
t-heading {
font-size:14px;
} 
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
t-heading {
font-size:24px;
} 
}
```

I would like to turn these into a mixin, so I can call these values inside other styles, while still keeping them responsive.

E.g.

SCSS:

```
.front {
background: red;
@include t-heading; 
}
```

Outputed CSS:

```
   .front {
    background:red;
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 599px) {
    .front {
    font-size:14px;
    } 

    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {

    .front {
    font-size:24px;
    } 
    }
```

Is this possible in SCSS? I have tried wrapping mixins in Media queries, but it doesn't seem to work.

*I am just using font-styles as an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the mixin to contain the media queries, not the other way around:

```
@mixin t-heading {
    @media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 599px) {
        font-size:14px;
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
        font-size:24px;
    } 
}

.front {
    background: red;
    @include t-heading; 
}
```

Output:

```
.front {
  background: red;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 599px) {
  .front {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .front {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}
```

Ideally, you'd want to avoid calling this sort of mixin very often, since that's a lot of extra code to be generating.  If the code is something you'll want to repeat, you might want to consider using `@extend`:

```
%t-heading {
    @media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 599px) {
        font-size:14px;
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
        font-size:24px;
    } 
}

.front {
    background: red;
    @extend %t-heading; 
}

.back {
    @extend %t-heading;
}
```

Output:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 599px) {
  .front, .back {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .front, .back {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}

.front {
  background: red;
}
```